# How to pass a file uploaded to another view (next page) for further processing

Tags: python, django, file, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a django app where I take an upload of a CSV file however once uploaded I want to simply display columns in another page of that CSV. Is there anyway to do this?

something like

```
def index(request):
    file = request.POST.get('file')
    redirect('nextpage', file)
```

Answer (score 0):

You question does not have enough data for one to provide solution. At least for entry level developers.
Post your model file

Comment: precious chicken, I don't have models, the intention is not to save the file but only process it after upload